# Finding the conserved region of protein in a given set of Kingdom

Tags: sequence-alignment, proteins

We have to find the conserved region of proteins in a given set of kingdom and we have to give more weightage to distantly related organism. What approach I should take to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to be able to answer the question better, could you explain what data/information do you have? Did you search for some terms related to your question? Why what you found didn't help? What else have you tried?